# Finding exact string from variable in an awk commmand?

Tags: awk, variable

I'm trying to the use the following awk command to return a user from a file that lists all users on the system but only if the 8th field is empty and they match the user variable (it's being using in a loop):

```
awk -F':' -v user="$user" 'index($0, user) {if ($8=="") print $1}' file
```

My issue currently is that it returns users that contain the string and aren't exact matches. Any way around this?

Comment: Even if you answered the question yourself it would be good to show some sample input and a corresponding username that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above answers are correct...However we can extract the details using the below command.

awk -F ',' '{if ( $9 == "" && $1 =="$user") print $1}' file

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

I ended up using:

```
awk -F':' -v user="$user" '$1 == user {if ($8 == "") print $1}' file
```

I'm a silly boy lol

Comment: Alternatively, `awk ... '$1 == user && $8 == "" { print $1 }'`

Comment: It's best to avoid `-v` and use environment variables instead (and `ENVIRON["VARNAME"]` in `awk`) as `-v` mangles values that contains backslashes. For instance, with `user='r\157ot'`, that would return the entry for `root` as `-v` would expand that `\157` to `o`